# How to define a JuMP expression conditional on index value

Tags: julia, expression, julia-jump

I am trying to define a `@NLexpression` in `JuMP` that has different specifications at different indices. In the below example, I want the expression `y[j,k]` to be defined as `1/(x[j] - x[k])` when `j != k` and take some other value when `j == k`. I can simulate this behavior by defining an auxiliary variable `z` and adding constraints conditional on index values. Is there a similar way to define expression conditional on index values?

```
using JuMP, Ipopt

model = JuMP.Model(with_optimizer(Ipopt.Optimizer))

@variable(model, 0 <= x[1:2])
@NLexpression(model, y[j=1:2,k=1:2], 1/(x[j] - x[k])) # <- problematic line

@variable(model, z[1:2,1:2])
for j=1:2, k=1:2
    if j == k
        @constraint(model, z[j,k] == 1)
    else
        @NLconstraint(model, z[j,k] == 1/(p[j] - p[k]))
    end
end

display(model)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're not obligated to use JuMP's macros to create containers for expressions. You should be able to conditionally create the expressions as follows:

```
model = JuMP.Model()

@variable(model, 0 <= x[1:2])
y = Dict()  # Or Array, if you prefer.
for j=1:2, k=1:2
    if j == k
        y[j,k] = 1
    else
        y[j,k] = @NLexpression(model, 1/(p[j] - p[k]))
    end
end
```